# Access full html field property from ClientModelValidationContext

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have a custom validation attribute that i'm moving across from asp.net to asn.net-core. It's a simple requiredif attribute implementing IClientModelValidator;

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

        private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-requiredif", ErrorMessage);

            //this following line is the issue
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty", (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName));
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-requiredif-desiredvalue", DesiredValue.ToString());

        }
    }
```

As i've commented above the line within the AddValidation method, I can't seem to get the full html field id like I used to in asp.net by casting the context to a ViewContext and accessing it's name that way.

What is the new way of getting the full html field id of a property that's not the current context?

For example the old code;

```
(context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName)
```

Might have returned a path such as "viewModel.ComplexObject.PropertyID".

I've tried looking in the context's ModelMetaData.ContainerContext But I can't guarantee that the properties container contains the property I need (it could be nested elsewhere within that).

For example, let's assume that my model looks like so;

```
 public class A
    {
        [RequiredIf("PropertyB", true)]
        public string propertyA { get; set; }

        public bool PropertyB { get; set; }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use following code in **AddValidation** method:

```
var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext viewContext;

var fullName = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(PropertyName);

var fullId = propertyFullName.Replace(".", "_");
```

Note: TemplateInfo now not have **GetFullHtmlFieldId** Method in asp.net core

Comment: Collections would also need: `.Replace("[", "_").Replace("]", "_")`