# What is the ASP.NET Core equivalent of ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("PropertyName")?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I'm migrating a web app to .NET Core, and it uses a few Razor editor templates for specific input types (e.g. outputting a `date` input for any `DateTime` model properties).

A couple of the templates use the following method to get the ID attribute value, for use elsewhere within the HTML:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("PropertyName")
```

However, this method no longer seems to exist in ASP.NET Core.

The `GetFullHtmlFieldName` method still exists, so it's possible to get the same result (at least for everything I've tested) by doing:

```
Regex.Replace(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("PropertyName"), @"[\.\[\]]", "_")
```

But this seems a little untidy to me, not to mention that there could be edge cases which the old method deals with that I don't know about.

Half an hour of googling, reading the [.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and searching SO hasn't turned up anything useful. The only thing I could find which was remotely relevant was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48181986/43140) (which just confirms the method is gone).

Does anyone know why `GetFullHtmlFieldId` no longer exists? Is it just an accidental omission, or is there a newer, better way of getting this now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a look through the ASP.NET Core repository, and it looks like `TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId()` was [originally removed](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/commit/f60f14d5377ce9043cd690580444910206f4ce95) due to a static reference to `HtmlHelper`.

After a lot of digging around (the .NET Core source browser is an *amazingly* useful tool), I think the solution for my problem is to use [`IHtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/IHtmlHelper.cs,f31c806af3a9c242,references). So, this code:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("PropertyName")
```

should now be written as:

```
Html.GenerateIdFromName(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("PropertyName"))
```

Still not all that tidy (or consistent), but at least this way we're re-using [the same internal logic](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/NameAndIdProvider.cs,69ce1f1d52d16395) that the framework uses to construct its IDs.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be hard to simulate the old behavior for your needs. Everything leads back to `TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId` which exists in .NET Core too, but it changed and the logic down to the path it changed.

`TemplateInfo` class had the following in `System.Web.Mvc`:

```
private string _htmlFieldPrefix;

public string HtmlFieldPrefix
{
    get { return _htmlFieldPrefix ?? String.Empty; }
    set { _htmlFieldPrefix = value; }
}

public string GetFullHtmlFieldId(string partialFieldName)
{
    return HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(GetFullHtmlFieldName(partialFieldName));
}

public string GetFullHtmlFieldName(string partialFieldName)
{
    // This uses "combine and trim" because either or both of these values might be empty
    return (HtmlFieldPrefix + "." + (partialFieldName ?? String.Empty)).Trim('.');
}
```

Afterwards it uses `HtmlHelper` to generate the id from the name:

```
public static string IdAttributeDotReplacement
{
   get { return WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement; }
   set { WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement = value; }
}

public static string GenerateIdFromName(string name, string idAttributeDotReplacement)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }

    if (idAttributeDotReplacement == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("idAttributeDotReplacement");
    }

    // TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId returns null for empty strings, return String.Empty instead to avoid breaking change
    if (name.Length == 0)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    return TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(name, idAttributeDotReplacement);
}
```

What needs to be researched and adjusted as per your needs:

1. `IdAttributeDotReplacement` property (gets or sets the character that is used to replace the dot (.) in the id attribute of rendered form controls) which also exists in .NET Core in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering`
2. `TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(name, idAttributeDotReplacement)` which I can see got modified to `TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(string name, string invalidCharReplacement);`

I don't really know about the method getting to be something else in .NET Core, but I'm looking forward to finding out.

Comment: This definitely helped me find the solution, so even though the comment box discourages 'thanks' comments: thanks!